# How to use camera capture event of a form in another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, camera

I am creating a new UI and I want to use the camera capturing event in the form1 on form2(in short, i am trying to transfer data from pictureBox1 of Form1 to pictureBox1 of Form2.) How can i achieve that?

Thanks...

Comment: Add a public method to Form2 (e.g., `public void SetImage(Image image) { pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose(); pictureBox1.Image = image; }`), or bind the two PictureBox Controls to the same Bitmap object (no need to dispose of anything in that case). It's not clear what you want to show in the second Form. -- Using a shared Bitmap could be better if you need to show the same exact *animation* in two controls.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I achieved what i wanted and shared it here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/536222/real-time-frame-of-webcam-capture-transfer-between.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In form 2, implement a public method to accept an image and display in the picture box
2. In form 1, in the PAINT event of the picture box, call the above method of Form 2

## Sample code

### Form 1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Object of Form 2 in Form 1
    Form2 oFrm2 = new Form2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Load an image in the picture box
        pictureBox1.Load(@"E:\Temp\SmartRetire.jpeg");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Consume the PAINT event of the picture box to notify a change in image
        pictureBox1.Paint += PictureBox1_Paint;
        //Show a blank form2
        oFrm2.Show();
    }

    //Raised when the picture box image is changed
    private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Show the image in form 2
        oFrm2.ShowImage(pictureBox1.Image);
    }
}
```

### Form 2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Public method called from Form1 when the image is changed in picture box (in form1)
    public void ShowImage(Image oImage)
    {
        //Display the picture in form2
        pictureBox1.Image = oImage;
    }

}
```